# Obtaining the last value that equals or most near in the column dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have an issue in my code, i'm making points of cuts.

First, this is my Dataframe Column:

```
In [23]: df['bad_%']

0       0.025
1       0.007
2       0.006
3       0.006
4       0.006
5       0.006
6       0.007
7       0.007
8       0.007
9       0.006
10      0.006
11      0.009
12      0.009
13      0.009
14      0.008
15      0.008
16      0.008
17      0.012
18      0.012
19      0.05
20      0.05
21      0.05
22      0.05
23      0.05
24      0.05
25      0.05
26      0.05
27      0.062
28      0.062
29      0.061

5143    0.166
5144    0.166
5145    0.166
5146    0.167
5147    0.167
5148    0.167
5149    0.167
5150    0.167
5151    0.05
5152    0.167
5153    0.167
5154    0.167
5155    0.167
5156    0.051
5157    0.052
5158    0.161
5159    0.149
5160    0.168
5161    0.168
5162    0.168
5163    0.168
5164    0.168
5165    0.168
5166    0.168
5167    0.168
5168    0.049
5169    0.168
5170    0.168
5171    0.168
5172    0.168
Name: bad%, Length: 5173, dtype: float64
```

I used this code to detected the value equals or most near to 0.05 (VALUE THAT INTRODUCED on the CONSOLE)

```
    error = 100                     #Margin of error
    valuesA = []                    #array to save data  
    pointCut=0                      #identify cut point
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if(abs(row['bad%'] - a) <= error):
            valuesA = row
            error = abs(row['bad%'] - a)         
            #Variable "a" introduced by console, in this case is "0.05"
            pointCut = index
```

This code return the value **"0.05"** in the index **5151**, in first instance looks good, because the **"0.05"** in the index "5151" is the last **"0.05"**.

```
Out [27]: 
5151    0.05
```

But my objetive is obtain **THE LAST VALUE IN THE COLUMN** **equal or most near** to **"0.05"**, in this case this value correspond to **"0.049"** in the index **"5168"**, i need obtain this value.

Exists an algorithm that permit this? Any solution or recomendation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "most near". x plusminus some epsilon value?

Answer (score 0):

Solutions if exist at leas one value:

Use `[::-1]` for swap values from back and get [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for last matched index value:

```
a = 0.05
s = df['bad%']

b = s[[(s[::-1] <= a).idxmax()]]
print (b)
5168    0.049
```

Or:

```
b = s[(s <= a)].iloc[[-1]]
print (b)
5168    0.049
Name: bad%, dtype: float64
```

---

Solution working also if value not exist - then empty `Series` yields:

```
a = 0.05
s = df['bad%']
m1 = (s <= a)
m2 = m1[::-1].cumsum().eq(1)

b = s[m1 & m2]
print (b)
5168    0.049
Name: bad%, dtype: float64
```

**Sample data**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bad%': {5146: 0.16699999999999998, 5147: 0.16699999999999998, 5148: 0.16699999999999998, 5149: 0.049, 5150: 0.16699999999999998, 5151: 0.05, 5152: 0.16699999999999998, 5167: 0.168, 5168: 0.049, 5169: 0.168}})
```

Comment: your code out me: [435:     0.049], in the df[bad%] rows(434-437) also have these values

Comment: For me working nice with data, added sample data to question. Maybe problem with float precision? How working with change a like `a= 0.04` ?